# How to execute a angular schematics from Oclif

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, angular-schematics, oclif

I'm writting a CLI using Oclif, and i try to exec a Custom Schematics that i build but if i launch separated using "ng add" command, the schematics ask correctly. If i launch schematic from Oclif, it don't ask anything.

Examples:

Works: In terminal: ng add D:/projects/schematics/ams-front-schematics

Don't works:

```
export default class New extends Command {
  static description = 'Generate new project based in archetype';

  static args: Parser.args.IArg[] = [ { name: 'PROJECT_NAME', required: true } ];

  private answers: any;

  async run(): Promise<any> {
    const { args }: { args: Parser.args.Output } = this.parse(New);
    const name: string = args.PROJECT_NAME;

    process.setMaxListeners(0);
    require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 100;
    await runCommand(`ng add D:/projects/schematics/ams-front-schematics`, {}, (...args: any[]) => this.log(...args)););
  }
}
```

Run command function only exec: npmRun library.

```
export function runCommand(commands: string, options: any = {}, debug: (...args: any[]) => void) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    debug('command', commands);
    npmRun.exec(commands, options, (err: any, stdout: any, stderr: any) => {
      debug('err', err);
      debug('stdout', stdout);
      debug('stderr', stderr);
      if (err) {
        debug(stderr);
        debug('End', err);
        resolve();
      } else {
        debug(stdout);
        debug('End', true);
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that simply by integrating angular schematics cli **@angular-devkit/schematics-cli** into your **oclif** project.

1. install angular schematics cli in your project by **npm i @angular-devkit/schematics-cli**
2. then install angular schematics in your project by **npm i @schematics/angular**
3. and after that update your main command file according to the below snippet. and simply run your cli by **./bin/run** from project dir

**Note:** For testing you have to run this command from angular project

```js
import { Command } from "@oclif/command";
import { main } from "@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/bin/schematics";

class AngularSchematicsCli extends Command {
  ...
  async run() {
    ...
    await main({
      args: ["@schematics/angular:component"],
    });
    
    // You can customise this args according to angular schematics 
    // args: ["@schematics/angular:component", "--name=test"],
  }
}

export = AngularSchematicsCli;
```